# How can I set position of edit control when EditFilter on CHeaderCtrl

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

I have custom class derived from CListCtrl.

When user click on column header I want to let him input text value. 
I found that I can do it by : CHeaderCtrl::EditFilter.
I expected that edit will be on the same position as text of column label. In fact it is bellow, so only part of control and text is visible. also part of column label is visible.
How can I set edit position to be covered by rect read by CHeaderCtrl::GetItemRect

[image: example preview]

```
void Data_list::OnHdnItemclickpointslist(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMHEADER phdr = reinterpret_cast<LPNMHEADER>(pNMHDR);
    CHeaderCtrl* header = this->GetHeaderCtrl();
    CRect rect;
    header->GetItemRect(phdr->iItem , rect );
    int iFilter = header->EditFilter(phdr->iItem , TRUE);

    // how to set position of edit
    *pResult = 0;
}
```

Comment: I would guess, the top-left corner of the ListView is about 4 pixels x 10 pixels away from top-left corner of parent window. You have to use `ClientToScreen` to find that offset. Or make sure ListView control is the parent of the Edit control.

Comment: OK, I can do that, but calculation of correct position is not what I need. More important for me is to findout how can I get any pointer to this edit.

Comment: Actually I didn't read the question right, my previous comment doesn't make sense. I am not familiar with `HDM_EDITFILTER` message and why it does that.

Comment: Are you trying to provide a mechanism for the user to update a specific 'cell' (row and column) value?

Comment: Yes, User want to input just one value, and each cell in this column will have new value calculated on input value.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment response, you should consider taking a different approach to gathering the data you want.  I’ve done something very similar using the following methodology.

- Create an Edit control class that will be used to collect the user
  data.  The class should be a child member variable of the CListCtrl.
- Handle the Left Button Down message from the list control.  In that
  handler, use the list control’s GetItemRect function to determine
  what row and column the user clicked.
- Create a dynamic Edit control over the top of the bounds of the cell
  the user clicked.  This will present a Edit control for the user to
  enter data.
- Detect when the user has finished entering data either through a lost
  focus on the edit control, or, some key sequence (e.g. Enter key).
- Notify the parent List control that editing has finished.  This can
  be done through messaging, or, a direct method call.  Make sure to
  pass the updated value to the parent List control.
- The parent list control should collect the passed updated valued and
  destroy the child Edit control.
- The parent list control should then iterate over the list control
  updating all “cells” in the selected column.

I did not provide actual code for this because there are many ways to accomplish the above methodology.  This should provide a starting point for you to implement an editing mechanism.

Comment: I also considered simmilar solution, probably I will do it in this way. 
Some time ago I tried to code it but I met another problem: Edit dynamicaly created was displayed until user move mouse above list header. In that case, Header was "refresh" and hide my edit.